# How do I achieve that zero is shown in numbers?

Tags: jquery

I am writing an application that outputs a price. My code for formatting the price is the following:

```
var preis_formatted = new Number(preis);
var preis_formatted = Number(preis_formatted.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString("nl-NL");
```

My problem: There are outputs like "26,4" where the 0 of decimals after the comma are not shown. How do I achieve that the output will be "26,40"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: ^That link will answer your question.

Comment: Wait you're already using `toFixed`?

Comment: First you parse it as a `Number`, then you format it (with `toFixed`), then you parse that *again* as a Number and then you format it again (with `toLocaleString`)... What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misplaced the paren. This:

```
var preis_formatted = Number(preis_formatted.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString("nl-NL");
```

Should be this:

```
var preis_formatted = Number(preis_formatted).toFixed(2).toLocaleString("nl-NL");
```

And also you don't really need that `toLocaleString`.